# how to implement tripwire in OpenCV using background subtraction

Tags: python, c++, opencv

The following [paper](http://research.ijcaonline.org/volume65/number8/pxc3885898.pdf) gives you an idea about tripwire.

I have subtracted the background from foreground using backgroundsubtractormog2 method of OpenCV C++.

I can able to find and draw contours but how to draw a line such that whenever a person or vehicle is crossing that line, it should be counted. you can see a sample video here [example video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z1Cvn3_4yGo).

Any suggestions on drawing such a line......

Is the way I am approaching is correct? I am using Windows 7 OpenCV 2 & OpenCV 3 in python and C++

Answer (score 0):

For drawing a line you can use the [cv::line](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#line) function.

For counting objects passing the line you can use the minimum and maximum (x,y) values of the contour or bounding box you know. If the contour has passed the line, then both minimum and maximum (x,y) will be on the other side of that line.

Can you show us the code of what you've already tried?

Comment: The link shows the code i am using:   http://study.marearts.com/2014/04/opencv-study-background-subtraction-and.html